An LED in series with a relay gets destroyed after a couple of activations
I've tried to make a bidirectional relay circuit with a pair of relays that work with 24 V. I tested the circuit and it works fine and both LEDs turn on when the relay is activated. After a couple of tries, one of the LEDs stopped working and burnt out. At first I thought I made a mistake so I replaced the burned LED with a new LED, but this scenario restarted again and after a couple of tries one of the LEDs was destroyed and only one works without any problem.
I might replace R2 & R5 as 1.2 kΩ (instead of 560 Ω) so the LED current will not exceed 20 mA. Could 20 mA be dangerous for a red LED? Can somebody tell me why my LED is destroyed?


Do you mean "LEDs in parallel" with your relays? Please edit your question to correct this. Also, are your LEDs simple 2 pin LEDs? Do you have a datasheet for them, or other specifications (like maximum current)?

Post the datasheet of the LED.

Unfortunately, you've used an unconventional layout for your schematic. Showing this circuit as two duplicates, with the 24V rail at the top and the GND rail at the bottom, makes it much easier for others to recognise and interpret. You've gone for a sort of symmetrical shape around a central 24V rail, maybe to save schematic sheet space, but you'll be able fit in a conventional arrangement in the same space. Remember that you draw/write something once but it's read a hundred times and by more people, so always try to make it easiest for the reader. You'd be well off redrawing this. Thanks.

You have a 1N4007 diode across each relay coil to clamp the back emf. This diode has a response time, which is slower when it was previously strongly reverse-biased as these are. So the 1N4007 will not instantly clamp away the back emf.
Typically, LEDs can only withstand a relatively low reverse voltage. Many are 2..3 V, look in the datasheet of yours.
You can protect the LED by putting a diode, such as another 1N4007, in series with the LED. This will block the back emf and should solve your problem.
Incidentally, 20 mA is a very high illumination current for a modern LED. It depends on the LED but look at using 5 mA or lower.

Schottky diodes (example 1N5619) in place of the 1N4007s will likely solve the problem.

The UF4007 is probably a better bet for clamping the spikes from the relay coils. Same ratings as the 1N4007 for voltage and current, but 70 nanosecond reverse recovery time.  The UF4007 costs a few cents more than the 1N4007.

@tonym thanks for the tip, yes I thought that diode may act funky but the strange thing is, if one of the diodes destroys the other diode works indefinitely, like my previous board

Reverse recovery time is not a critical factor for diode used across a relay coil since it only needs to rapidly turn on but not off, so there's no reason to go from a 1N4007 to a UF4007.
